# I have a excel sheet with some header and footer and data in between , now I want edit one column of that dataframe in between

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xlsxwriter, pandas.excelwriter

I have a excel sheet with some header and footer and data in between , now I want edit one column of that dataframe in between such that I don't want to change any other thing. That one column as you can see in the link as well as the photo is the LOAN NO. For example in the given dataset ,I want to change the loan no. from row 6 to xyzzz from abcd|xyzzz and dont want to change a single thing other than this and save the file back in the excel format.

When reading the file in pd.read_excel it formats some data(messes up the columns,unnamed etc), how else should I do this in python?

P.S- there's a one row footer in the end as well
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gJ97HpG3OJlrcQswI2BIWLsZluza4PEm/view?usp=drivesdk

[Here's the link to the dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gJ97HpG3OJlrcQswI2BIWLsZluza4PEm/view?usp=drivesdk)

[image: Here's a screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
# pip install openpyxl
df = pd.read_excel('./sample23.xlsx', 'Sheet0', header=None)
def change(x):    
    try:
        if x != 'abcd|xyzzz' and x == 'Loan No.':
            return x
        elif x == 'abcd|xyzzz':
            return 'xyzzz' 
    except Exception as e:
        return x


df[6] = df.apply(lambda row: change(row[6]), axis=1)
df.to_excel("test.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet0', header=None, index=None)

df.head(10)
```